# Access Google Apps users from Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps

Is there a way to access the Google Apps users for my domain from a Google App Engine App on uploaded on that domain. I know I can use it for authentication, and I could build queries to the Google Apps api that would pull this data up, I was just wondering if there is a native way to take care of this. I would be writing in python, but I am not sure how useful that is, I feel that all that is available in python is available in the java backend as well

Comment: May be this [reporting API](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/reporting/google_apps_reporting_api.html) can help you.

Comment: What do you mean "access Google Apps users"? What do you want to do to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not an App Engine-specific API, but you can use the gdata-python library. See [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/retrieving_gdata_feeds.html).